# ASP.NET Core MVC: WCF client does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-core-mvc, wsdl, .net-7.0

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC project with a WCF. I published my WCF to a remote server with IIS and consumed the client via:

> Right click "Connected Services" > Manage Connected Services > Add New Service Reference

I pasted the link of the WSDL from the .svc page. The only custom settings I set is that I checked "Generate Synchronous Operations" and clicked "Finish". When I tried to initialize the WCF client, I am getting the following error:

```
'BillingSVCClient' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments
```

Here are my codes currently:

**Reference.cs** (Generated by Visual Studio)

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace BillingSVC
{
    
    
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.1.0")]
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName="BillingSVC.IBillingSVC")]
    public interface IBillingSVC
    {
        
        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IBillingSVC/AddConnectionType", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IBillingSVC/AddConnectionTypeResponse")]
        void AddConnectionType(string conType, int classificationID, string code);
        
        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IBillingSVC/AddConnectionType", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IBillingSVC/AddConnectionTypeResponse")]
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task AddConnectionTypeAsync(string conType, int classificationID, string code);
        
        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IBillingSVC/UpdateConnectionType", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IBillingSVC/UpdateConnectionTypeResponse")]
        void UpdateConnectionType(int conTypeID, string conType, int classificationID, string code);
        
        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IBillingSVC/UpdateConnectionType", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IBillingSVC/UpdateConnectionTypeResponse")]
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task UpdateConnectionTypeAsync(int conTypeID, string conType, int classificationID, string code);
        
        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IBillingSVC/DeleteConnectionType", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IBillingSVC/DeleteConnectionTypeResponse")]
        void DeleteConnectionType(int conTypeID);
        
        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IBillingSVC/DeleteConnectionType", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IBillingSVC/DeleteConnectionTypeResponse")]
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task DeleteConnectionTypeAsync(int conTypeID);
    }
    
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.1.0")]
    public interface IBillingSVCChannel : BillingSVC.IBillingSVC, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel
    {
    }
    
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.1.0")]
    public partial class BillingSVCClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<BillingSVC.IBillingSVC>, BillingSVC.IBillingSVC
    {
        
        /// <summary>
        /// Implement this partial method to configure the service endpoint.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="serviceEndpoint">The endpoint to configure</param>
        /// <param name="clientCredentials">The client credentials</param>
        static partial void ConfigureEndpoint(System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, System.ServiceModel.Description.ClientCredentials clientCredentials);
        
        public BillingSVCClient(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration) : 
                base(BillingSVCClient.GetBindingForEndpoint(endpointConfiguration), BillingSVCClient.GetEndpointAddress(endpointConfiguration))
        {
            this.Endpoint.Name = endpointConfiguration.ToString();
            ConfigureEndpoint(this.Endpoint, this.ClientCredentials);
        }
        
        public BillingSVCClient(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration, string remoteAddress) : 
                base(BillingSVCClient.GetBindingForEndpoint(endpointConfiguration), new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(remoteAddress))
        {
            this.Endpoint.Name = endpointConfiguration.ToString();
            ConfigureEndpoint(this.Endpoint, this.ClientCredentials);
        }
        
        public BillingSVCClient(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
                base(BillingSVCClient.GetBindingForEndpoint(endpointConfiguration), remoteAddress)
        {
            this.Endpoint.Name = endpointConfiguration.ToString();
            ConfigureEndpoint(this.Endpoint, this.ClientCredentials);
        }
        
        public BillingSVCClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
                base(binding, remoteAddress)
        {
        }

        public void AddConnectionType(string conType, int classificationID, string code)
        {
            base.Channel.AddConnectionType(conType, classificationID, code);
        }
        
        public System.Threading.Tasks.Task AddConnectionTypeAsync(string conType, int classificationID, string code)
        {
            return base.Channel.AddConnectionTypeAsync(conType, classificationID, code);
        }
        
        public void UpdateConnectionType(int conTypeID, string conType, int classificationID, string code)
        {
            base.Channel.UpdateConnectionType(conTypeID, conType, classificationID, code);
        }
        
        public System.Threading.Tasks.Task UpdateConnectionTypeAsync(int conTypeID, string conType, int classificationID, string code)
        {
            return base.Channel.UpdateConnectionTypeAsync(conTypeID, conType, classificationID, code);
        }
        
        public void DeleteConnectionType(int conTypeID)
        {
            base.Channel.DeleteConnectionType(conTypeID);
        }
        
        public System.Threading.Tasks.Task DeleteConnectionTypeAsync(int conTypeID)
        {
            return base.Channel.DeleteConnectionTypeAsync(conTypeID);
        }
        
        public virtual System.Threading.Tasks.Task OpenAsync()
        {
            return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.FromAsync(((System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject)(this)).BeginOpen(null, null), new System.Action<System.IAsyncResult>(((System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject)(this)).EndOpen));
        }
        
        private static System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding GetBindingForEndpoint(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration)
        {
            if ((endpointConfiguration == EndpointConfiguration.BasicHttpBinding_IBillingSVC))
            {
                System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding result = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding();
                result.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
                result.ReaderQuotas = System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max;
                result.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
                result.AllowCookies = true;
                return result;
            }
            if ((endpointConfiguration == EndpointConfiguration.BasicHttpsBinding_IBillingSVC))
            {
                System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding result = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding();
                result.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
                result.ReaderQuotas = System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max;
                result.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
                result.AllowCookies = true;
                result.Security.Mode = System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
                return result;
            }
            throw new System.InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Could not find endpoint with name \'{0}\'.", endpointConfiguration));
        }
        
        private static System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress GetEndpointAddress(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration)
        {
            if ((endpointConfiguration == EndpointConfiguration.BasicHttpBinding_IBillingSVC))
            {
                return new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("http://192.168.2.160/CEDCBS_Overhaul_DevJD/BillingSVC.svc");
            }
            if ((endpointConfiguration == EndpointConfiguration.BasicHttpsBinding_IBillingSVC))
            {
                return new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("https://egstestdeploy/CEDCBS_Overhaul_DevJD/BillingSVC.svc");
            }
            throw new System.InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Could not find endpoint with name \'{0}\'.", endpointConfiguration));
        }
        
        public enum EndpointConfiguration
        {
            
            BasicHttpBinding_IBillingSVC,
            
            BasicHttpsBinding_IBillingSVC,
        }
    }
}
```

**MyController.cs**

```
public class Maintenance : Controller
{
    private readonly BillingSVCClient client = new BillingSVCClient(); // This is where the error occurs
    
    // Some IActionResult code here...
    
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddConnectionType(string conType, int classificationID, string code) 
    {
        await client.OpenAsync();
        client.AddConnectionType(conType, classificationID, code);
        client.Close();
    
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

I am used to initialize WCF this way on my old ASP.NET MVC projects but it seems ASP.NET Core MVC works in a different way. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

## UPDATE Jan 20, 2024

[Qi You's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77844076/8331324) answer points to the cause of the problem. But in addition to his answer, I needed to add the following functions:

```
private static System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding GetDefaultBinding()
{
    return BillingSVCClient.GetBindingForEndpoint(EndpointConfiguration.BasicHttpBinding_IBillingSVC);
}

private static System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress GetDefaultEndpointAddress()
{
    return BillingSVCClient.GetEndpointAddress(EndpointConfiguration.BasicHttpBinding_IBillingSVC);
}

//public enum EndpointConfiguration code here...
```

And change `endpointConfiguration.ToString();` to `EndpointConfiguration.BasicHttpBinding_IBillingSVC.ToString();` on the **BillingSVCClient** from his answer.

Resulting with this **Reference.cs**

**Reference.cs** (as of Jan 20, 2024)

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace BillingSVC
{
    
    
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.1.0")]
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName="BillingSVC.IBillingSVC")]
    public interface IBillingSVC
    {
        
        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IBillingSVC/AddConnectionType", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IBillingSVC/AddConnectionTypeResponse")]
        void AddConnectionType(string conType, int classificationID, string code);
        
        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IBillingSVC/AddConnectionType", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IBillingSVC/AddConnectionTypeResponse")]
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task AddConnectionTypeAsync(string conType, int classificationID, string code);
        
        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IBillingSVC/UpdateConnectionType", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IBillingSVC/UpdateConnectionTypeResponse")]
        void UpdateConnectionType(int conTypeID, string conType, int classificationID, string code);
        
        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IBillingSVC/UpdateConnectionType", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IBillingSVC/UpdateConnectionTypeResponse")]
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task UpdateConnectionTypeAsync(int conTypeID, string conType, int classificationID, string code);
        
        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IBillingSVC/DeleteConnectionType", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IBillingSVC/DeleteConnectionTypeResponse")]
        void DeleteConnectionType(int conTypeID);
        
        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IBillingSVC/DeleteConnectionType", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IBillingSVC/DeleteConnectionTypeResponse")]
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task DeleteConnectionTypeAsync(int conTypeID);
    }
    
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.1.0")]
    public interface IBillingSVCChannel : BillingSVC.IBillingSVC, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel
    {
    }
    
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.1.0")]
    public partial class BillingSVCClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<BillingSVC.IBillingSVC>, BillingSVC.IBillingSVC
    {
        
        /// <summary>
        /// Implement this partial method to configure the service endpoint.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="serviceEndpoint">The endpoint to configure</param>
        /// <param name="clientCredentials">The client credentials</param>
        static partial void ConfigureEndpoint(System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, System.ServiceModel.Description.ClientCredentials clientCredentials);

        public BillingSVCClient() :
         base(BillingSVCClient.GetDefaultBinding(), BillingSVCClient.GetDefaultEndpointAddress())
        {
            this.Endpoint.Name = EndpointConfiguration.BasicHttpBinding_IBillingSVC.ToString();
            ConfigureEndpoint(this.Endpoint, this.ClientCredentials);
        }

        public BillingSVCClient(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration) : 
                base(BillingSVCClient.GetBindingForEndpoint(endpointConfiguration), BillingSVCClient.GetEndpointAddress(endpointConfiguration))
        {
            this.Endpoint.Name = endpointConfiguration.ToString();
            ConfigureEndpoint(this.Endpoint, this.ClientCredentials);
        }
        
        public BillingSVCClient(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration, string remoteAddress) : 
                base(BillingSVCClient.GetBindingForEndpoint(endpointConfiguration), new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(remoteAddress))
        {
            this.Endpoint.Name = endpointConfiguration.ToString();
            ConfigureEndpoint(this.Endpoint, this.ClientCredentials);
        }
        
        public BillingSVCClient(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
                base(BillingSVCClient.GetBindingForEndpoint(endpointConfiguration), remoteAddress)
        {
            this.Endpoint.Name = endpointConfiguration.ToString();
            ConfigureEndpoint(this.Endpoint, this.ClientCredentials);
        }
        
        public BillingSVCClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
                base(binding, remoteAddress)
        {
        }
        
        public void AddConnectionType(string conType, int classificationID, string code)
        {
            base.Channel.AddConnectionType(conType, classificationID, code);
        }
        
        public System.Threading.Tasks.Task AddConnectionTypeAsync(string conType, int classificationID, string code)
        {
            return base.Channel.AddConnectionTypeAsync(conType, classificationID, code);
        }
        
        public void UpdateConnectionType(int conTypeID, string conType, int classificationID, string code)
        {
            base.Channel.UpdateConnectionType(conTypeID, conType, classificationID, code);
        }
        
        public System.Threading.Tasks.Task UpdateConnectionTypeAsync(int conTypeID, string conType, int classificationID, string code)
        {
            return base.Channel.UpdateConnectionTypeAsync(conTypeID, conType, classificationID, code);
        }
        
        public void DeleteConnectionType(int conTypeID)
        {
            base.Channel.DeleteConnectionType(conTypeID);
        }
        
        public System.Threading.Tasks.Task DeleteConnectionTypeAsync(int conTypeID)
        {
            return base.Channel.DeleteConnectionTypeAsync(conTypeID);
        }
        
        public virtual System.Threading.Tasks.Task OpenAsync()
        {
            return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.FromAsync(((System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject)(this)).BeginOpen(null, null), new System.Action<System.IAsyncResult>(((System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject)(this)).EndOpen));
        }
        
        private static System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding GetBindingForEndpoint(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration)
        {
            if ((endpointConfiguration == EndpointConfiguration.BasicHttpBinding_IBillingSVC))
            {
                System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding result = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding();
                result.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
                result.ReaderQuotas = System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max;
                result.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
                result.AllowCookies = true;
                return result;
            }
            if ((endpointConfiguration == EndpointConfiguration.BasicHttpsBinding_IBillingSVC))
            {
                System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding result = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding();
                result.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
                result.ReaderQuotas = System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max;
                result.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
                result.AllowCookies = true;
                result.Security.Mode = System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
                return result;
            }
            throw new System.InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Could not find endpoint with name \'{0}\'.", endpointConfiguration));
        }
        
        private static System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress GetEndpointAddress(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration)
        {
            if ((endpointConfiguration == EndpointConfiguration.BasicHttpBinding_IBillingSVC))
            {
                return new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("http://192.168.2.160/CEDCBS_Overhaul_DevJD/BillingSVC.svc");
            }
            if ((endpointConfiguration == EndpointConfiguration.BasicHttpsBinding_IBillingSVC))
            {
                return new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("https://egstestdeploy/CEDCBS_Overhaul_DevJD/BillingSVC.svc");
            }
            throw new System.InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Could not find endpoint with name \'{0}\'.", endpointConfiguration));
        }

        private static System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding GetDefaultBinding()
        {
            return BillingSVCClient.GetBindingForEndpoint(EndpointConfiguration.BasicHttpBinding_IBillingSVC);
        }

        private static System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress GetDefaultEndpointAddress()
        {
            return BillingSVCClient.GetEndpointAddress(EndpointConfiguration.BasicHttpBinding_IBillingSVC);
        }

        public enum EndpointConfiguration
        {
            
            BasicHttpBinding_IBillingSVC,
            
            BasicHttpsBinding_IBillingSVC,
        }
    }
}
```

Now my question is why does **svcutil.exe** doesn't generate these codes automatically when consuming the WSDL?

Comment: I did two kinds of tests: 1.Version. Such as(**.Net Framework 3.0**, **.Net Framework 3.5**, **.Net Framework 4.7.2**, **.Net Framework 4.8**, **.Net Framework 4.8.1**). The results I get are all there.

Comment: 2. **Project templates**. Such as(**WCF Service**, **WCF Service Application**, ""Console App**). The results I get are all there.

Comment: I think it should be your Svcutil .exe problem.I recommend you uninstall and reinstall.

Comment: Is the WCF Service Application published to IIS with a .NET CLR Version 4.0? Also, are you using [dot-net svcutil](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/dotnet-svcutil-guide?tabs=dotnetsvcutil2x)?

Comment: Yes. I think you can try reinstalling or testing with a different device. Because this is the code that is automatically generated.

Answer (score 3):

Add code to **Reference.cs**

```
public BillingSVCClient() : 
         base(BillingSVCClient.GetDefaultBinding(), BillingSVCClient.GetDefaultEndpointAddress())
 {
     this.Endpoint.Name = endpointConfiguration.ToString();
     ConfigureEndpoint(this.Endpoint, this.ClientCredentials);
 }
```

Comment: This works but I needed to also manually add `GetDefaultBinding()` and `GetDefaultEndpointAddress()`. In addition to this, I needed to change `endpointConfiguration.ToString();` to `EndpointConfiguration.BasicHttpBinding_IBillingSVC.ToString();`

My another question is why **svcutil.exe** doesn't automatically generate these codes. Do you have an idea why this happens?

Comment: I don't think this problem is probably caused by **svcutil.exe** . **svcutil.exe** is a tool for generating service model code. It generates service model code from metadata documents, and metadata documents from service model code. However, **svcutil.exe** does not automatically generate **public BillingSVCClient()**. **ClientBase <T>** is usually written on the client side. You can try testing an initial service to see if the same issue exists.

Comment: I tested it by making a new fresh WCF Application project and published to IIS. Still the methods aren't generated just like this issue. Here's the generated Reference.cs: https://pastebin.com/CJQsmkNT

Comment: Keep Reference.cs auto-generated (by svcutil.exe) and move your custom code into another file (e.g. BillingSVCClient.custom.cs). Take advantage of the fact that svcutil.exe generates a partial class, and hence gives you the option of adding your custom code in a separate file.